# JavaScript to accept all friends in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to accept all friends in facebook. I refer to this article, and use the following code:

```
var confirmBtns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < confirmBtns.length; i++) {

if (confirmBtns[i].innerHTML == "Confirm") {

confirmBtns[i].click();

}

}
```

However, when executing it in Chrome, I get the following result:

```
undefined
```

Why?

Thanks

Comment: You would have to understand the code and debug it. You can't just copy code and when it doesn't work ask someone else to figure out why.

Comment: @WizKid, Thank you for your comment. I understand the code. It just find all "Button" elements, then use a loop to check each button element and if its innerHTML is "Confirm", i.e., the Confirm button, then perform the click on that element.

Comment: Does it find any buttons? Does it find a Confirm button? What is outputting undefined?

Comment: @WizKid, I check the source HTML of https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests, it seems that facebook has changed their codes a lot so this code snippet does not work any more. I will close this question. Thank you very much for your attention and helps.